# Convert from sbyte[] to SByte[] for an matlab event

Tags: c#, arrays

I allocate data memory from unmanaged code in byte[]. Iam able to convert that array in sbyte[] and give it per event to an matlab listener. But matlab is not able to interpret this data as sbyte[]. 
But Matlab is able to understand the System.SByte[] Object. So i want to convert the sbyte[] array to an SByte[] and give to the matlab script.

But i dont want to copy each element to an new array.

Does anybody has experience with that?

Comment: um.... `sbyte` ***is*** `System.SByte`. They are **exactly** the same thing. Hence `sbyte[]` ***is*** `System.SByte[]`... can you be more specific about the error that occurs here?

Answer (score 1):

A frivolous answer here would be:

```
sbyte[] arr = GetData();
System.SByte[] arr2 = arr;
CallMatlab(arr2);
```

However, this is basically a non-answer, because it *doesn't do anything*. `sbyte` is simply an *alias* to `global::System.SByte`. They are *precisely* the same thing. No conversion is necessary or appropriate, because *they already are the same thing* (ignoring deliberate edge-cases like declaring your own local type called `SByte`). C# is not like Java; in Java there is an important difference between (for example) `int` and `Integer`; in C#, this simply is not the case: `int` === `System.Int32`.